# Allowed operations on an possibly invalid pointer by the strict interpretation of the C Standard

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, c89

#### Original Question

*(please see "Edit: Updated scenario")*

This question might be a duplicate in one or another way to a huge collection of questions around undefined behavior of pointers to objects that gone out of scope etc. But all questions I found here to this topic are mostly specialized use cases. So I would like to spin the question upside down, not asking if something is forbidden, but WHAT exactly is allowed?

To have a possible scenario: You have a function, that takes a pointer - you don't know if it came from a (still) valid object. Which operations are under **all circumstances NOT** undefined behavior? Which might have unspecified side conditions?

```
int * myFunc(const int * const A, int * B)
{
   ...
}
```

**Edit: Updated Secenario**

In the comments to the question and [Matt McNabbs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31329698/3364914) it was pointed out that UB has risen most likely anyway, as an invalid pointer(s value) is used during call the function in the scenario. Therefore I will change the scenario a little (following the example from [Keith Thompsons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324268/3364914)):

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
/* the value of ptr is now valid, possibly NULL */
if (ptr != NULL) 
{
    /* the value of ptr is valid and non-null */
    free(ptr);
    /* the value of ptr is now invalid */

    ... /* here operations in question */
}
```

---

#### List of allowed operations:

*(To be completed and corrected by your answers and comments.)*

- Well defined: Take the size of the pointer variable. E.g. `sizeof(ptr)`
- Well defined: Take the size of the dereferenced pointer (given it is not `void *`). E.g. `sizeof(*ptr)` (see comments of [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323226/allowed-operations-on-an-possibly-invalid-pointer-by-the-strict-interpretation-o#comment50634381_31323226) and [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) ).
- Well defined: Assignment of another (valid) value to the pointer (not to the referenced variable!). E.g. `ptr = NULL;`
- Well defined: Accessing the representation of the Pointer (example from [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324268/3364914)):

  ```
  unsigned char rep[sizeof ptr];
  memcpy(rep, &ptr, sizeof ptr); /* ok, accesses the representation */
                                 /* but not the value */
  ```

#### Operations that are not well-defined according to the standard:

*(To be completed and corrected by your answers and comments.)*

These operations are often treated as if they are well-defined on an invalid pointer, but are not well-defined according to the standard:

- Undefined: Comparing the value of the pointer (even to a NULL-Pointer constant)
- Undefined: conversion to an integral value

As with all undefined behaviour, you may get away with (ab)using the pointers on many machines, but the C Standard does not guarantee that you will get away with and there are (or once were) machines where such abuse of a pointer would lead to programs failing dramatically.

For the general rule, see [Keith Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324268/3364914) — and the extensive comments below.

Comment: I, and probably Mark A, am interested in knowing why people are downvoting. This seems like a good enough question to me...

Comment: Didn't downvote but the premises of this question are wrong as (from C Rationale): *"Regardless how an invalid pointer is created, any use of it yields undefined behavior. Even assignment, comparison with a null pointer constant, or comparison with itself, might on some systems result in an exception."*

Comment: @Jashaszun This question is way too broad.

Comment: So... what you say then is that there are no allowed operations... that is quite harsh. Thank you for that piece of information.

Comment: @Jashaszun How can the question at the same time be to broad and result in "nothing is allowed"? :-)

Comment: @MarkA. That's what I'm wondering. This question does not seem too broad for me, as there is a specific set of allowed operations (in this case, "nothing"). It doesn't take paragraphs to list.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82946/discussion-on-question-by-mark-a-allowed-operations-on-an-possibly-invalid-poin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any use of an invalid pointer *value* has undefined behavior.

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
// the value of ptr is now valid, possibly NULL
if (ptr != NULL) {
    // the value of ptr is valid and non-null
    free(ptr);
    // the value of ptr is now invalid
    ptr; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
}
```

Citation: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.4p2:

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
>   the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

It's likely that a compiler will generate no code for the expression statement `ptr;`; that is, of course, within the bounds of undefined behavior.

Any operation on the pointer *object* that doesn't retrieve its value is (at least potentially) well defined:

```
sizeof ptr;  // ok, doesn't use the value
sizeof *ptr; // ok, doesn't use the value, only the type
ptr = NULL;  // ok
```

You can also access the *representation* of the pointer object without accessing its value:

```
unsigned char rep[sizeof ptr];
memcpy(rep, &ptr, sizeof ptr); // ok, accesses the representation
                               // but not the value
```

though there's not much you can do with the result.

Comment: Even though code may access the representation of a pointer, there's no guarantee that the bytes obtained thereby can be put to any useful purpose.  Given `char *p,*q; p=calloc(1,1); free(p); q=calloc(1,1);` it would, I think, be legitimate for `if (!memcmp(&p, &q, sizeof p)) (*p)++;` to launch nuclear missiles since `p` is illegitimate, `q` could legitimately have the same representation, and the act of observing that `p` and `q` have the same bitwise representation would do nothing to make `p` valid.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad. But to answer your specific scenario:

```
int * myFunc(const int * const A, int * B)
```

If this function were called with an invalid pointer value then *it already caused undefined behaviour* by evaluating the invalid pointer value as part of preparing to call the function.

All of your bullet points "well defined" are not well defined, since once UB has happened the cat cannot be put back in the bag.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what causes the invalid pointer to be evaluated in preparing to call the function?

Comment: Yes - my scenario is not very helping the question - I see - you are totally right on that - an UB must have happend, if we get an alreadly invalid pointer
 But at least there is one situation I can think of, in which the pointer (out of our control) was valid on the entry point of the function, and might not be at the point we operate on it:
The function might be interrupted and the pointer got freed in an "parallel" task.

Comment: Also - beside the missleading scenario, there seems to be a really limited set of operations, that are applicable an will always result in UB. - In which sense is my question very broad?

Comment: @GreenAsJade yes, specifying it as the function argument

Comment: @MarkA. many operations will result in UB and it's complicated. It depends on whether the system has hardware trap representations, and since C11 whether you ever took the address of the variable, and it differs between C89/C99/C11

Comment: @MarkA. I'm not an expert on C11 threads, but I think if there is no memory fence separating the free from the evaluation of the pointer then it is undefined behaviour (same as if it were modifying an integer)

Comment: Regading the many "UB operations"... I suspected so... thats why I specifically ask for operations, that will ALWAYS NOT (instead of NOT ALWAYS :-) ) result in UB. And it seems as there IS a very limited set to this.

Comment: I have updated the scenario - please check if it is now more clear and supports the question better.

Comment: @M.M: Whether UB occurs does not depend upon whether the system has hardware trap representations.  If the system doesn't have trap representations and a compiler author recognizes that quality implementations for platforms that can cheaply and easily implement reliably-useful behaviors in cases beyond those mandated by the Standard should often do so, then many algorithms can be simplified.  Unfortunately, many compiler writers interpret permission to behave in nonsensical fashion (when absolutely necessary) as an invitation to do so (even when not necessary nor beneficial).