# Integer representation(s) of NULL constant: Guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: c, pointers, null, c89

This is a "according to the very words of the C-Standard"-Question. Is it guaranteed, that a cast from NULL to an unsigned integer, big enough to hold any pointer, results in the same value, irrespectively of the type of the pointer, that holds NULL?

Please see the following piece of code, where T1, T2 might be of any type constructable in C:

```
#include <stddef.h>

/* unsigned int be known to be big enough to hold any object pointer */
unsigned int ui_ptr1, ui_ptr2, ui_ptr3, res;

ui_ptr1 = (unsigned int) NULL;
ui_ptr2 = (unsigned int) (T1 *) NULL;
ui_ptr3 = (unsigned int) (T2 *) NULL;

res = (ui_ptr1 == ui_ptr2) && (ui_ptr1 == ui_ptr3);
```

Is `res` guaranteed to be `1` for any T1 and T2?
From ISO:9899:1990 (C90) I know, that NULL is equivalent to an implementation defined null-pointer constant (7.1.6). And I know that conversion form a given pointer type, and back again is well defined, but the value is implementation defined. (6.3.4; G.3.7, 2. "-").

But I cannot find any argumentation on the above. Have I missed something? Are there more guarantees in more... recent... C Standard iterations?

**Background:**
I want to transport a pointer between functions via an unsigned integer (I have no choice here) through some static variable, that need to initialized proper by a 3. instance. The initializing instance does not know the type of the pointer to be transported, so it needs to initialize with a integer constant (without casts evolved), that but then represents a/the correct NULL-Pointer constant. If not undefined behavior is lurking, when I try to do anything with it. (see also: [Allowed operations on an possibly invalid pointer by the strict interpretation of the C Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323226/allowed-operations-on-an-possibly-invalid-pointer-by-the-strict-interpretation-o)).

Comment: I can not help you with the c-standard reference. But If your pointer datatype is always of the same length (no raw memory transition between machines of different sizes), NULL should always be 0. type does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From C99 and C11, 6.3.2.3 p3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. 55) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

And p4:

> Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type. Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

(Also, footnote 56/67 remarks that "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment").

(A draft of C89 has the equivalent text to the C99 quoted above in section 3.2.2.3).

So, it seems fairly safe to assume, on an architecture with a linear addressing scheme and where the pointer size is equal to the word size, that a single integer value represents `NULL` - especially if you go through the `void *` type. In theory though, a `NULL` pointer (even `void *`) when converted to an integer might not equal 0, since that's not mandated. You can get around this by always converting through `void *` before comparing whether the value represents `NULL`.

That is, if you change your above declarations of ui_ptr2 and ui_ptr3 to:

```
ui_ptr2 = (unsigned int) (void *) (T1 *) NULL;
ui_ptr3 = (unsigned int) (void *) (T2 *) NULL;
```

... then you can at least be sure that each of:

```
(void *) ui_ptr2 == (void *) ui_ptr3
(void *) ui_ptr2 == NULL
(void *) ui_ptr3 == NULL
```

... will be true. If you cast either `(void *) ui_ptr2` or `(void *) ui_ptr3` to some other pointer type, it should still be `NULL`, as per 6.3.2.3 p4 quoted above.

You are, however, relying on the conversion of pointer-to-integer being reversible. The conversion is implementation defined, in both directions, and though one would hope that converting a pointer to an integer and then back to a pointer yields the original pointer value, that's not strictly mandated (though footnote 56 quoted above strongly recommends it by implication). Furthermore there is no guarantee that all possible pointer values are representable in *any* integer type (6.3.2.3 p6). Your only real way around this is to verify that `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(void *)` and then use `memcpy` to transfer the representation of the pointer to the integer, and back, in which case there is no longer a need to go via `void *` (just so long as the type of the pointer you store is the same as the type you retrieve).

Comment: I just came to the same idea right a minute ago - checking for C90 atm. Thank you for the quick answer. So to be save, the backward way from integer to pointer also has to go through void * ,...

Comment: @MarkA. Yes, you always need to go through `void *`.

Comment: Nice - a new 1-liner pattern I have to explain with 10 lines of comments :-)
I will wait a little, if some others find a short cut, though, before I accept the answer. If you like and can, please add the lines of C90 and C11.

Comment: @MarkA. done; for C11 it's the same as C99, for C89/90 it's 3.2.2.3.

Comment: @MarkA. It's also worth noting that you cannot have this work at all without relying on some implementation-defined behavior, because the conversion between pointer and integer is implementation-defined. In particular (from p6) "The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type" in which case you in fact have UB.

Comment: Regarding the integer and back conversion - C89 its comment 45. You are right, that it is not absolutely mandated that after conversion, there it is still a valid pointer (to the same object)... anyway comment 45 is good enough I think :-)

Comment: I see nothing that would mandate that repeated conversions of the same pointer (null or otherwise) to uintptr_t must yield the same value.  If a pointer contains a 16-bit segment and 32-bit offset, and the segment is padded to make the pointer size a multiple of 32 bits, then `uintptr_t` would likely be a `uint64_t`, but a statement like `someUintPtr = somePtr` might store 48 bits into `someUintPtr` and leave the remaining 16 bits holding whatever they held before the assignment.

Comment: @MarkA.: If `ptr` is a valid `void*`, then after `uintptr_t x = (uintptr_t)ptr, y = (uintptr_t)ptr;` it would be guaranteed that `(void*)x == (void*)y`, but that doesn't imply that `x==y`.  See my previous comment for a plausible implementation where that might not be the case.

Comment: @supercat nothing _mandates_ it, right; I already state something to that effect in my answer: "In theory though, a NULL pointer (even void *) when converted to an integer might not equal 0, since that's not mandated". For the purposes of the question though, you can check that an integer is the result of conversion from `NULL` by converting it back to `void *` first, assuming that the conversion was successful in both directions - again, as already stated in the answer.

Comment: @davmac: My intended point was that an implementation need not be deliberately perverse to cause such behavior; I don't know if 80386 segmented-mode compilers store 48-bit pointers with 32-bit alignment, but it's certainly plausible that some might do so (among other things, so the memory layouts of `void*` and `uintptr_t` would match).  Since `mov segReg,[effectiveAddr]` is a 16-bit store, the upper 16 bits of the `uintptr_t` would only be cleared if software expended an extra instruction clearing it.

Comment: @supercat very well, edited: "So, it seems fairly safe to assume, _on an architecture with a linear addressing scheme and where the pointer size is equal to the word size,_ that a single integer value represents NULL"